# Eclipse custom console button position

Tags: eclipse, button, plugins, position

I have created an eclipse plugin that implements custom consoles, and in this console view I have made a button that terminates a process when it is pressed.
Now I want that this button to be positioned before all of the console's button.
I know that I have to modify my `location URI`, but I can't find the value to use for `?before=`.
Could you help in telling me what is that value?
This is how the button is positioned now and I want it before all the buttons. It is the red `X`

[image: This is the termination button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ConsoleView` view toolbar is created like this:

```java
protected void configureToolBar(IToolBarManager mgr) {
    mgr.add(new Separator(IConsoleConstants.LAUNCH_GROUP));
    mgr.add(new Separator(IConsoleConstants.OUTPUT_GROUP));
    mgr.add(new Separator("fixedGroup"));
    ...
```

So your before value should probably be the value of `IConsoleConstants.LAUNCH_GROUP` which is `launchGroup`:

```java
/**
 * Menu group identifier for the console view context menu and toolbar, for actions pertaining to
 * launching (value <code>"launchGroup"</code>).
 */
public static final String LAUNCH_GROUP = "launchGroup";

/**
 * Menu group identifier for the console view context menu and toolbar, for actions pertaining to
 * console output. (value<code>"outputGroup"</code>).
 */
public static final String OUTPUT_GROUP = "outputGroup";
```